# Search a non visible field in Vuetify-js Datatable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating an expandable datatable in **Vuetify**.

Only 5 columns are displayed in the table headers. When you expand each line, you get the detailed information, using the `item.data-table-expand` slot, which shows more columns available in the data array.

Now I want to be able to apply a search filter on the table.

My problem is that the `search` directive only searchs in the fields declared in the headers (the 5 columns), and I need to search in the other fields.

I tried adding a searchable field in the headers, but there is no way to hide it so it wont be shown.

I also tried the `custom-filter` to use my own function, but it is called once per header field, not once per row (where I could access the rest of the fields).

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `custom-filter`...

```
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    show-expand
    single-expand
    item-key="name"
    :search="search"
    :custom-filter="customSearch">
  </v-data-table>

  methods: {
    customSearch (value, search, item) {
      return Object.values(item).some(v=>v&&v.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search))
    }
  },
```

https://codeply.com/p/jraMEhXaCk

Comment: Hi Zim. Thank you so much! I had completely misunderstood the documentation, and I thought the custom filter could only access header fields, when it can access the complete data in the array (the "item"). I see the function is called once for every searchable field, so I made only one field searchable, and used that call to search the hidden field. Thanks!