# Vuetify: Searching a v-data-table by multiple values?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-card-title>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        label="Search Product Name"
        single-line
        hide-details
    ></v-text-field>
</v-card-title>
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="this.$store.getters['options/getAllAvailableProducts']"
    :items-per-page="10"
    :search="search"
    class="elevation-1"
>
</v-data-table>


///

data() {
    return {
        dialog: this.$store.getters['liveDashboard/getShowDynamicSelectionModal'],
        search: '',
        headers: [
            { text: 'Image',
              value: 'thumb',
              sortable: false,
            },
            {
              text: 'Product',
              sortable: true,
              value: 'product_name',
            },
            {
              text: 'Price',
              sortable: false,
              value: 'inventory_min',
            },
            {
              text: 'Inventory',
              sortable: true,
              value: 'inventory_quantity',
            },
            {
              text: '',
              sortable: true,
              value: 'inventory_id',
            },
        ],
    }
},
```

I have a data table populated by `products`.  A single `product` has multiple fields:

example:

the value of `this.$store.getters['options/getAllAvailableProducts']` is an array of products.

```
   [
     {
       'product_name': "test test",
       'sku': "145534",
       'brand': "Nike",
       'inventory_id': 4,
       'inventory_min': 44,
       'inventory_quantity': 2,
     },
     {
       'product_name': "new product",
       'sku': "5534545",
       'brand': "Nike test",
       'inventory_id': 5,
       'inventory_min': 512,
       'inventory_quantity': 44, 
     }
   ]
```

Right now, typing in the name of the product brings up the products that match the name but I want it to where typing in the name, sku or brand will bring up all the matching products.

So typing in "test" would bring up both of those products since the first product has "test" in the `name` field and the 2nd product has "test" in the `brand` name.

Comment: @Zim wow I can't believe I forgot that part.  just added

Comment: just added the correct structure to the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify's data-table is only searchable on the fields that are defined in the `headers` prop.

However, you can get it to search *all* fields by using a `custom-filter`...

```
<v-card>
  <v-card-title>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="search"
      label="Search"
      single-line
      hide-details
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-card-title>
  <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      :custom-filter="customSearch"
   >
   </v-data-table>
</v-card>


methods: {
      customSearch (value, search, item) {
          return Object.values(item).some(v=>v&&v.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search))
      }
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Ggkbu9cSpk)

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940776/search-a-non-visible-field-in-vuetify-js-datatable/62943241#62943241).